# Как создать загрузочную microSD флешку c Windows 7 под Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-7, ntfs, ubuntu

Форматирую флешку в NTFS, устанавливаю флаг boot, с помощью unetbootin пробую записать windows на флешку, но unetbootin не видит флешку с ntfs. Может есть какие-то альтернативы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мудрить ничего не надо.
Создаётся primary раздел. Делается активным, форматируется в NTFS.
Далее просто копируется содержимое iso-образа на этот раздел.

Тип флешки/hdd/sdd не имеет значения. Данный метод работает и с более свежими версиями windows — 8/8.1/10tpreview

Answer (score 0):

есть инструмент позволяющий делать это автоматически просто выбрав флешку и образ с которого эту флешку будите делать

http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool